# Is it possible to measure the inclination of a line using only subtraction (and not division)?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**Context**. I can see that the reason a slope is measured as a ratio is because it works quite well.  Something that varies more than something else yields a ratio greater than 1.  That's how useful division is --- it serves us when distributing money among people, but it also lets us compare quantities.  When measuring a slope, we are interested in comparing two numbers, two variations.  But subtraction is also a way to compare numbers and I've been trying to use subtraction to somehow get a coherent way to measure the inclination of a line.  I have not succeeded, but I can't quite pinpoint where the trouble is.

**Question**.  Is it possible to measure the inclination of a line using only subtraction?  How would you do this?  (If it is possible, the next question would be --- why did mathematicians choose division over subtraction?  For instance, subtraction seems cheaper.)

Comment: It allows you to compute the average speed of a car in km/h even if the car was only travelling for 37 minutes.

Comment: Well, that's essentially the idea of establishing the limit of f(x+h) when h gets arbitrarily small. Bring the two end points of the slope as close together as imagination allows, and you'll be left with a simple subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are two aspects to your question. One of them is roughly "Why do we have division at all? Isn't subtraction sufficient for comparing numbers?" Well, they are related (by $e^{x-y}=\frac{e^x}{e^y}$ and $\log\frac xy=\log x-\log y$) but they tell us different things. A ratio is something invariant under multiplication of both quantities by the same amount: $\frac{kx}{ky}=\frac xy$, whereas a difference is invariant under adding the same amount to both quantities: $(x+k)-(y+k)=x-y$. Notice that on the other hand, the relationships $\frac{x+k}{y+k}=\frac xy$ and $kx-ky=x-y$ are not generally true.

So the other part of your question seems to be "why is division the right operation for measuring the inclination of a line?" Well, on any line, multiplying $\Delta x$ by $k$ results in multiplying $\Delta y$ by $k$ too (e.g. if you go twice as far right you'll go twice as far up), so the comparison operation we want is the one invariant under multiplication.

Consider the line that goes through the points $(10,101),(20,201),(30,301),(40,401)$. How would you describe its inclination? If you move 10 units right, you go 100 units up; if you move 20 units right, you go 200 units up, and so on; we always have $\Delta y=10\Delta x$, so the ratio $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is a constant (namely 10, the slope) that serves as a measure of the line's inclination. If we instead compute some non-constant quantity like $\Delta y-\Delta x$ that changes depending on which points we use, then it's telling us something about the chosen points but not about the underlying line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  Looking at your example, I computed $\Delta y = 100$, $\Delta x = 10$ using "adjacent" points.  That produces $\Delta y - \Delta x = 90$.  If I take the points $(10,101), (40, 401)$, the difference $\Delta y - \Delta x$ comes out as $270$, which is the three times $90$.  Couldn't we somehow also specify that we need to divide the different by the length of the interval?  Okay, I think we'd be using division again --- which should be outside of the legal rules here, right?  Thank you.

Comment: Exactly - you could use $\frac{\Delta y-\Delta x}{\Delta x}$ as your measure of inclination (equivalent to $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}-1$), but it's the division that's making it independent of the chosen points.